# Software caused connection abort Client receive

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception

I'm making an app in Android studio and I'm getting an IOException which is unpredictable nor have I managed to replicate it.

```
W/TcpProtocolLayer: Connection to /x.x.x.x:x  closed.
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:421)
W/System.err:     at x.x.protocol.layer.TcpProtocolLayer.receive(TcpProtocolLayer.java:254)
W/System.err:     at x.x.protocol.layer.TcpProtocolLayer.receive(TcpProtocolLayer.java:201)
W/System.err:     at x.x.protocol.layer.DatagramProtocolLayer.receive(DatagramProtocolLayer.java:133)
W/System.err:     at x.x.protocol.ProtocolStack.receive(ProtocolStack.java:190)
W/System.err:     at x.x.protocol.Socket.receive(Socket.java:85)
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around it and I just can't seem to understand why this would happen, for legal reasons I can't show the code where it's happening but I can describe it.

The phone sends a message to a server and the server responds. This part is always successful and never fails. Then the phone waits for the server to send another message for a confirmation, and this is where it the exception happens. It might throw the exception instantly it might throw it after 10 seconds. I should also say that 90% of the time the code works just fine and no exception is thrown and it processes the information just fine. Then the 10% of the unpredictable attempts this happens and breaks the app completely. I've watched out for it not to be a Async Thread error ,and I've concluded it isn't and the Socket is opened at the moment of this happening. If anyone has any answer I'd be happy to hear it because this problem has been haunting me for a month already and I can't fix it

Comment: This error was caused because the device was switching network routers while communicating so if anyone else fins this there you go , hope this helps :D